# Binding NSPopUpButton to an NSArray

Tags: binding, nsarray, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

I want to populate an NSPopUpButton with an array of NSStrings. I also want to be able to set the selected item in the NSPopUpButton as well as get the selected value. Is there a way to do this using bindings? Here's what I have that only has the content of the array controller bound to arragedObjects.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray;
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *myPopUpButton;
    IBOutlet NSArrayController *processArrayController;   
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
     NSString *firstObject = @"Lustre";
     NSString *secondObject = @"TwoTone Laser";
     NSString *thirdObject = @"Laser Mark";
     NSString *forthObject = @"Double Lustre";
     NSString *fifthObject = @"CG Ink";

    // Create the array
     myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstObject, secondObject,  
     thirdObject, forthObject, fifthObject, nil];

    // Sort the array
    [myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    // Set contents of the array controller that is bound to the popup button
    [processArrayController setContent:myArray];

    // Set a selection to an item of the popup button
    [myPopUpButton  selectItemWithTitle: firstObject];  
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an ivar in your application controller to hold your selection:

```
@property (copy) NSString *selection;
```

And of course, synthesize it in your implementation file.

Make these bindings to your NSPopUpButton instance:

**Content:**

Bind To: Array Controller (unless you've given your array controller another name)

Controller Key: arrangedObjects

**Content Values:**

Bind To: Array Controller (unless you've given your array controller another name)

Controller Key: arrangedObjects

Model Key Path: (for strings, I've always used 'description')

**Selected Object:**

Bind To: App Delegate (unless you've given your application delegate another name)

Model Key Path: self.selection

Finally, since your popup button is now bound to `selection`, this is how you set up your initial selection:

```
self.selection = firstObject;
```

Good luck to you in your endeavors.